# a simple assembly question

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I'm new to assembly, and it's quite fun. Anyways I have one question...

```
cmpw cr7, %r29, %r8
```

Is that code the equivalent of `if cr7 > %r29 and %r8`?

Comment: It will probably help others to give your architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares r29 to r8 and places the result in cr7 I believe.

In other words:

cr7 = r29 - r8

After reading some PPC docs, it looks like cr (the comparison register), gets a coded value, representing less, greater, equal.

```
less:    0x100
greater: 0x010
equal:   0x001
```

In other architectures, such as x86, there is no CR per se, but a group of flags, such as ZF, SF, and CF (zero, sign, and carry flags).  Those are always set during arithmetic operations, such as subtraction.  Hence a compare is basically the same as a subtract.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But why the subraction?

Comment: Comparison is really just a subtraction.  If you compare A and B, A is less than B if A-B is negative.  It is more than B if A-B is positive, and they are equal if A-B==0.  However, I am not 100% sure that PPC stores the subtracted result.  I found some documentation which states that the cr gets values of 4, 2, and 1, for less, greater, equal, respectively.

Comment: Ah, okay. Here's the full code:
cmpw   cr7, %r29, %r8
beq     cr7, loc_152A13

Comment: The `beq` is `branch if equal`, in other words, jump to loc_152A13 if r29 and r8 are equal.  BEQ looks at the result stored in cr7.

Comment: Most architectures have a "flags" register, where the flags are updated after an operation (such as the subtraction implied by a "compare" opcode) and states how the operation went (e.g. "there was a carry"). The conditional jump opcodes interpret the flags, depending on the kind of jump. PowerPC is "special" in that it precomputes the interpretations (it does not store "the result is negative" but "if you want to do a 'jump if smaller' then here is the result"), and also it has 8 flags registers, not 1; they are called cr0 to cr7.